# Click on cell button to display angular-material 2 modal window in Ag Grid

Tags: angular, angular-material2, ag-grid

I am using Ag Grid in Angular 5. Here i am showing data from api. I am using angular material 2 for designing purpose. I want to include a button in ag-grid in which i click that button. After clicking the button a angular material modal will open. I am trying a lot of time but can not figure it. Is there any way to solution?

company.component.ts

```
export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {
private gridApi;
private gridColumnApi;
public columnDefs;

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, public snackbar: MatSnackBar, 
public dialog: MatDialog) {
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Action',
    field: 'action',
    width: 150,
    suppressFilter: true,
    },
  {
    headerName: 'Id',
    field: 'id',
    filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
    width: 80,
    maxWidth: 100,
    suppressMenu: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Company Name',
    field: 'companyName',
    width: 160,
    suppressMenu: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Address',
    field: 'companyAddress',
    width: 160,
    suppressFilter: true,
    },
  {
    headerName: 'Phone',
    field: 'phone',
    width: 130,
    suppressMenu: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Fax',
    field: 'fax',
    width: 130,
    suppressMenu: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Email',
    field: 'email',
    width: 150,
    suppressMenu: true

  },
  {
    headerName: 'Note',
    field: 'note',
    width: 200,
    suppressFilter: true
    },
  {
    headerName: 'Activation Status',
    field: 'appConfActivationStatusStatusName',
    width: 70,
    suppressMenu: true
  }
 ];
}

getCompanyInfo(params) {
this.gridApi = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
this.httpClient.get('http://192.168.10.208:9092/hrm/companyList')
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      params.api.setRowData(data);
    },
    msg => {
      console.error(`Error: ${msg.status} ${msg.statusText}`);
    }
  );

  }
}
```

company.component.html

```
  <ag-grid-angular
#agGrid
style="width: 100%; height: 80%;"
id="myGrid"
class="ag-theme-balham"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[enableSorting]="true"
[paginationPageSize]="5"
[pagination]="true"
[enableColResize]="true"
[enableFilter]="true"
[floatingFilter]="true"
(gridReady)="getCompanyInfo($event)">
[![enter image description here][1]][1]</ag-grid-angular>
```

Comment: Please share your existing code

Comment: i have shared my code @bugs

Answer (score 4):

I am not familiar with how ag-grid exactly works, [this is a working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2azph) of a `material-table` that opens a `material-modal` when clicking on the first column of each entry (1,2,3 etc.), you should be able to easily extend this example to your use case.

**EDIT: ag-grid version**

You can listen to the `rowClicked` event to display the modal. Have a look at this implementation:

```js
<ag-grid-angular
    #agGrid
    style="width: 100%; height: 80%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [enableSorting]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="5"
    [pagination]="true"
    [enableColResize]="true"
    [enableFilter]="true"
    [floatingFilter]="true"
    (rowClicked)="openDialog()"
    (gridReady)="getCompanyInfo($event)">
 </ag-grid-angular>
```

```js
export class CompanyComponent implements OnInit {
private gridApi;
private gridColumnApi;
public columnDefs;

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, public snackbar: MatSnackBar, 
public dialog: MatDialog) {
this.columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: 'Action',
    field: 'action',
    width: 150,
    suppressFilter: true,
    },
  {
    headerName: 'Id',
    field: 'id',
    filter: 'agNumberColumnFilter',
    width: 80,
    maxWidth: 100,
    suppressMenu: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Company Name',
    field: 'companyName',
    width: 160,
    suppressMenu: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Address',
    field: 'companyAddress',
    width: 160,
    suppressFilter: true,
    },
  {
    headerName: 'Phone',
    field: 'phone',
    width: 130,
    suppressMenu: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Fax',
    field: 'fax',
    width: 130,
    suppressMenu: true
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Email',
    field: 'email',
    width: 150,
    suppressMenu: true

  },
  {
    headerName: 'Note',
    field: 'note',
    width: 200,
    suppressFilter: true
    },
  {
    headerName: 'Activation Status',
    field: 'appConfActivationStatusStatusName',
    width: 70,
    suppressMenu: true
  }
 ];
}

openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDataExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px'
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }

getCompanyInfo(params) {
this.gridApi = params.api;
this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
this.httpClient.get('http://192.168.10.208:9092/hrm/companyList')
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      params.api.setRowData(data);
    },
    msg => {
      console.error(`Error: ${msg.status} ${msg.statusText}`);
    }
  );

  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-data-example-dialog',
  template: '123',
})
export class DialogDataExampleDialog {
  constructor( @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

Comment: Let me see if I have some time to implement it with ag-grid

Comment: I've modified the answer to include an example with ag-grid

Comment: It's quite simple. I should have done this. Thanks a lot @bugs

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, so that other people can benefit from it in the future

Comment: RowClicked doesn't really answer the question. What if your row has many buttons? I've seen the CellClicked event where you can look at which column was clicked and handle accordingly. But, what if your cell has multiple buttons? Ag-Grid did not make this easy.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
 onRowClicked(event) {
    this.dialog.open(Component);
  }
```